# Count time diff based on status

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table

```
ID    | Date     | Time     | Status  
73937 | 3/1/2012 | 17:25:00 | Pending        |     
73938 | 3/1/2012 | 17:27:00 | Pending        | time diff 2 min  
73948 | 3/1/2012 | 17:29:00 | Pending        | time diff 2 min  
73952 | 3/1/2012 | 17:45:00 | Stop Clock     | time diff 16 min   
74967 | 3/1/2012 | 19:15:00 | Stop Clock     | time diff 0 min  
74970 | 3/1/2012 | 20:15:00 | Pending Active | time diff 60 min  
74972 | 3/1/2012 | 20:21:00 | Active         | time diff 6 min
```

How can I calculate time diff where the status is not `Stop Clock` and summarize the time diff in MySql?
You can see if the status is `Stop Clock` will stop count (0 min).

Comment: You are going to need to explain better what you want.  Show the output you wish to see for the input data.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the datatype of field Time?

Comment: This would have been a very trivial task, had you decided to use the `DATETIME` field type MySQL comes with.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry if i not give the type.. for Date (Date) and Time (Time) ..i decided to not use DATETIME because i need to show them in different text field.. @Mosty --> thx for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This query:

```
select id, date, time, status, hour(diff) * 60 + minute(diff) Diff from (
  select id, date,
    if(@active or status != 'StopClock',
       timediff(addtime(date, time), @prevTime), 0) Diff,
    time(@prevTime := addtime(date, time)) time,
    @active := status != 'StopClock',
    status
  from t, (select @prevTime := 0, @active := false) init
  order by id
) final
```

Would result in:

```
+-------+------------+----------+---------------+------+
|  ID   |    DATE    |   TIME   |    STATUS     | DIFF |
+-------+------------+----------+---------------+------+
| 73937 | 2012-03-01 | 17:25:00 | Pending       |      |
| 73938 | 2012-03-01 | 17:27:00 | Pending       |    2 |
| 73948 | 2012-03-01 | 17:29:00 | Pending       |    2 |
| 73952 | 2012-03-01 | 17:45:00 | StopClock     |   16 |
| 74967 | 2012-03-01 | 19:15:00 | StopClock     |    0 |
| 74970 | 2012-03-01 | 20:15:00 | PendingActive |   60 |
| 74972 | 2012-03-01 | 20:21:00 | Active        |    6 |
+-------+------------+----------+---------------+------+
```

Note that, for some reason, you're not taking seconds into account. Let me know if you have any issue with this.

Comment: hi mosty....you're good!! i already try your code and just what i expected!! thx!

Comment: Welcome! You should accept the answer, then :) See you around!

Comment: @Mosty...i need to sum 'DIFF' column :(