# Calculate diff time in MySQL between to status records

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-python

This is one of my MySQL tables:

| idpk | id | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 43857 | AVAILABLE | 2023-01-07 09:14:19 |
| 2 | 43857 | OFFLINE | 2023-01-07 18:14:19 |
| 3 | 43857 | AVAILABLE | 2023-01-07 23:14:19 |
| 4 | 43860 | AVAILABLE | 2023-01-08 09:14:19 |
| 5 | 43860 | OFFLINE | 2023-01-08 18:14:19 |
| 6 | 43860 | AVAILABLE | 2023-01-08 22:14:19 |
| 7 | 43857 | OFFLINE | 2023-01-08 23:14:19 |

I track multiple id's and the it's current status. My goal is to know the offline time of each ID within 24 hours.

For example:

> ```
> id -> 43857 on 2023-01-07 it would be an offline time of 5 hours.
> id -> 43860 on 2023-01-08 it would be an offline time of 4 hours.
> ```

The calculation should be only if status is "OFFLINE" until next "AVAILABLE" status.

Currently I do this via python, I select affected rows within 24 hours, calculate and save the offline time in another table.

Is there a better way to calculate this? For example in SQL language?

I'm also open to new ideas, better ways to save the data in MySQL to make the calculation easier.

Btw.:
I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713701/count-time-diff-based-on-status) which is pretty much what I need, but can someone explain me that query a little bit?

Comment: What if the latest status for a given date was 'OFFLINE' and the following 'AVAILABLE' never came?

Comment: If status is OFFLINE @ 2023-01-07 22:00:00 and then AVAILABLE @ 2023-01-08 01:00:00, do you account for 2 hrs on 2023-01-07 and 1 hr on 2023-01-08 or do you attribute 3 hrs to one of the two days? If the latter, which day do you attribute the downtime to? Can there be consecutive OFFLINE records, or are these effectively records of state change? Is it possible for the downtime to last more than 24 hrs? If so, would there be at least one OFFLINE record per day?

Answer (score 0):

This would eliminate all time stamps that have no available status reached

```
WITH CTE as (SELECT
t1.id, t1.`timestamp`
  , (SELECT `timestamp` FROM tab1 t2 WHERE  t2.id = t1.id 
  AND t2.`status`= 'AVAILABLE'  
  AND t1.`timestamp` < t2.`timestamp` 
  ORDER BY t2.`idpk` ASC LIMIT 1) atime
FROM tab1 t1 
WHERE t1.`status`  = 'OFFLINE'
)
SELECT 
  id,
CONCAT(
TIMESTAMPDIFF(day,`timestamp`,atime) , ' days ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(hour,`timestamp`,atime), 24), ' hours ',
MOD( TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute,`timestamp`,atime), 60), ' minutes '
, ' OFFLINE') `offline`
  FROM CTE
WHERE atime IS NOT NULL
```

| id | offline |
| --- | --- |
| 43857 | 0 days 5 hours 0 minutes OFFLINE |
| 43860 | 0 days 4 hours 0 minutes OFFLINE |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/szdIzAC4)